Can't generate large document because of too little memory (error: "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]");
I was trying to generate a document containing some very large tables. With a program written in C I generated a logarithm table which is about half a million lines long (this is the length of the text file formatted using latex notation). The expected pdf document should be about 3300 pages long. However my tex engine fails at line ~ 35000 (when the pdf is only at page ~ 200) giving the error message "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]. \hline  ". I'm using TexLive with pdflatex engine on Ubuntu. I have two question:

Can I greatly increase the memory allocated to TexLive in order to be able to compile my document?
Can I write my document in a different way such that I can divide my document in smaller chunks which the compiler can generate without having to increase the memory and then unite them in a single pdf?

Here I show how a typical page on my document is formatted.
'''
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    1.152522260799691 & 0.061649322509766\\
    \hline
    1.152532384213657 & 0.061653137207031\\
    \hline
    1.152542507716543 & 0.061656951904297\\
    \hline
    ...
    1.152097157698506 & 0.061489105224609\\
    \hline
    1.152107277378492 & 0.061492919921875\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    1.152117397147366 & 0.061496734619141\\
    \hline
    1.152127517005130 & 0.061500549316406\\
    \hline
    ...
    1.152502014238519 & 0.061641693115234\\
    \hline
    1.152512137474645 & 0.061645507812500\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\pagebreak

'''

How many lines are in a typical single tabular? Normally TeX shouldn't have any issues with long documents, provided you don't put everything into a single paragraph/box.

in a single tabular envirormnet there are 40 lines

tex normally outputs each page (and frees memory) as soon as output so it is very unusual to get that error with normal tables. Do you have these in a float that is held to the end?

TeX normally outputs each page (and frees memory) as soon as a page is output so it is very unusual to get that error with normal tables. Do you have these in a float that is held to the end?
You only show two tabular which are side by side in the same paragraph, is that intended? also you use \pagebreak not \newpage so that also does not free memory as it does not end the paragraph.
The fragment shown would use a lot less memory if there was a blank line between the tabular so they are in separate paragraphs, and if you used \clearpage rather than \pagebreak so that a page was output at that point, rather than at the end of the paragarph (in code not shown in your fragment)

Thank you, thank you so much. It compiled! I didn't t know there was a difference between \pagebreak and \clearpage. Thank you again

Although TeX outputs page by page, the pdf backend holds everything in memory (not too sure this is from observation).

@yannisl some global structures and references need to be held but i don't think it holds the actual pdf content, You can have a documents of tens of thousands of pages without a linear increase in memory consumption. But the difference between holding a thousand tabels in a thousand paragraphs and holding a thousand tables in one paragraph then linebreaking them one per line, is essentially a thousandfold increase in memory consumption. having a single rather than double newline between the tabular is expensive:-)

I hit the same issue on texlive 2023. I assume, you are on texlive 2024, but maybe this trick works:
Find the file /texlive/2024/texmf.cnf and add two lines:
  pool_size = 15000000
  main_memory = 10000000

Depending on the RAM of your machine...

I don't have a 2023 or 2024 directory. Do I have to create one and in the new directory create a file containing these two lines?

@StefanoBelli no you should have a local texmf.cnf somewhere at the root of your tex tree. depending where you installed tex that might be in a different location.
